# search using Range slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, rangeslider

The problem is how i use the values of javascript variables in php for query.

here is my code for range slider

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4 /jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: 71,
        max: 109,
        values: [75, 100],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $("#size-range").html(Math.floor(ui.values[0] / 12) + "'" + (ui.values[0] % 12) + '" - ' + Math.floor(ui.values[1] / 12) + "'" + (ui.values[1] % 12) + '"');
            $("#min_inches").val(ui.values[0]);
            $("#max_inches").val(ui.values[1]);
        }
    });
    $("#size-range").html(Math.floor($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) / 12) + "'" + ($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) % 12) + '" - ' + Math.floor($("#slider-range").slider("values", 1) / 12) + "'" + ($("#slider-range").slider("values", 1) % 12) + '"');
    $("#min_inches").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0));
    $("#max_inches").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));
});
 </script>

 <p>Size Range: <strong><span id="size-range"></span></strong> <small><em>(drag slider handles below to specify)</em></small></p>

<div id="slider-range"></div>

<input type="text" name="min_inches" id="min_inches" value="" />
<input type="text" name="max_inches" id="max_inches" value="" />
```

Any help would be appreciated.